# Fast way to confirm the center point and path

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv

I have the following gray image. I can use `np.transpose(np.nonzero(tmpData))` to find the location of point. My original idea is calculating the euclidean distance for all point to check which point repeating present. And based on this idea to find which path correlated with this center point.

However, this approach is quite slow. I need 2 loop for calculating euclidean distance. 1 loop for finding the center point. And 1 loop for confirming which direction it has.

Is there any faster way to find the center point and the path?

point location:

```
[ 74 374]
[ 20 440]
[149 325]
[269  52]
[242 149]
[252 254]
[209 329]
[349 256]
[449 252]
[549 245]
[649 241]
[732 258]
[780 316]
```

[image]

Comment: Are you defining the center point as "the point which has the most points within some distance" or "the point which shows up most frequently when looking within some distance of each point"? It's a little hard to tell which way you mean (it's possible that both are equivalent but I'm not sure yet)

Comment: My definition is the point connect 2 or more different path. In the above image, you can see that there exist 3 different path. And both of them are correlated with the center point (inside the red circle)

Comment: I agree that *I* can see the different paths, but it's not clear how the computer would know that. For example, you can draw a line from *any* of the points to the center; how does your program know that say, any of the points on the bottom path should go along the path at all? 

I'm not sure if it would work *in general* for any of your use cases, but if you can narrow down pictures that look this good typically, then the Euclidean minimum spanning tree should give you the exact tree you're looking for and the maximal node (most edges) would be the center. IIRC MST is linear, `O(n)`.

Comment: Can you provide a few more sample images please?

Comment: Please also show your code.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there will always be an actual point at the place where paths intersect? Are the spacings between the points always the same? If they are variable, is that the result of speed differences, and if so do the point spacings (i.e. speed) stay constant within each path?

Comment: What are the points anyway please?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can think of is using a [Random sample consensus algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus). I once used this to reconstruct a 3D solid from a point cloud. Since your example is 2D, it would repeatedly pick 2 random points and check how many points are within a certain threshold of the line that can be constructed from those 2 points. The algorithm would ideally find 3 lines, approximating the 'paths' you are talking about. The intersections of those lines would give a good indication of where you should be looking for the center point.

**edit:**  to get the three lines, you can remove points from the data set. So, first it finds the best fit and then you remove the points within the threshold of that fit. After this, it looks for the next best fit, and so on. You can do that using a while loop with as condition the number of points that are left. To make it more clear with your example:

This is the first line you find:

[image]

So now you remove the points from the set in which you are fitting lines and go on, this is the second line:

[image]

Remove the points from the second line and then fit the last line to the points that are left:

[image]

There are no points left to fit, so this means that your crossing should be somewhere near these 3 intersection points:

[image]

You can consider putting your data in a tree structure like a [balltree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) to look for the common closest neighbors of those 3 intersections points.

With RANSAC it is possible that you get less or more lines than you want, or that the lines do not fit correctly. This all depends on the parameters (you can optimize those by trial and error) and the data.

note: the example above is just a demonstration I made with matplotlib, I did not use a RANSAC algorithm but the result would somewhat be the same.

Comment: Solid use of Ransac!

Comment: Could you provide more information? I know that RANSAC can find one best line to fit all point. But how to get 3 different line? Running the algorithms three times?